# Porqué se ejecuta la primera línea de código de la función antes de ser llamada(UnboundLocalError: local variable 'plan' referenced before assignment)

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, clase

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
plan=[]

def newUser():
    plan[0] = input('Introduce tu plan (Lite/Pro/Mega): ')
    print(plan[0])

newUser()
```

La primera línea de código de la función se ejecuta antes de que se llame a la misma, y luego cuando se llama la función da el siguiente error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'plan' referenced before assignment

**¿Qué debo hacer para evitar que se ejecute la primera línea de la función antes de ser llamada?**

**Dejo también un enlace al vídeo debuggeando el código para que veáis en concreto**

> https://mega.nz/file/g1tSTQiA#Uf4Xwo28nnw_I9ml-NWr9kI_7Wly5b26YmMnesn7gjA

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Coloca un [repro] _en la pregunta_. Lee [ask].

Comment: La función no se ejecuta antes de ser llamada. El error se debe a que intentas guardar en una lista (`plan[0]`) que aún no has creado.

Comment: el error se da por el nivel del scope , en python la variable esta declarada en el nivel global pero dentro de la funcion el buscara la interna una solucion es hacer: `def newUser(): global plan` indicando que se usara la varible plan del scope global.

Comment: creo que en el encabezado de la funcion deberias poner `global plan` y listo amigo.

Answer (score -1):

Prueba poniendolo de esta manera:

```
def newUser():
    plan = input('Introduce tu plan (Lite/Pro/Mega): ')
    print(plan)

newUser()
```

Así usas una variable en lugar de un array para guardar el valor, que es lo que está causando el problema.

Comment: Falta explicar cual fue el error cometido y explicar la solución. Un código sin más no es de utilidad para nadie más.